# does tomcat have main method internally? if yes how does it resolves conflict with Spring Boot applications *main*?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

Does tomcat have *main* method internally? If **yes**, how does it resolves conflict with `Spring Boot` applications `main`?

As per my knowledge, every program must start with an entry point i.e. `main` method.

Comment: Tne entry point is the Spring Boot application's main , then Spring will start Tomcat (don't know how it is done internally, one way is by calling the `main` method of `org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap` )

Comment: Spring Boot runnable jars create and configure an instance of `embedded` tomcat. No other main methods required.

Answer (score 0):

In your spring-boot application you should have class Application, which would be as you said the entry point for your application. There is no conflicts to start it on the tomcat server.

You should configure your maven to pack application to WAR for example and then deploy it on the server.

Here is the helpful guide for you: [CLICK](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html)